# Jquery $.ajax special characters issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using this jquery .ajax function to save comments on a form:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        data: {"yourname": yourname,
             "yourmessage": yourmessage},
        type: "POST",
        url: "xxx.php",
        timeout: 20000,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(data){...}
        }
    });
```

Here is the PHP page called:

```
$yourname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['yourname']));
$yourmessage = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['yourmessage']));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `reactions` VALUES ('".$yourname."','".$yourmessage."')");
```

The special characters are not registered correctly, hence I am getting this as a result:

"C\'est Ã  Ã§a que tu rÃ©fÃ¨res?" instead of "C'est à  ça que tu réfères?"

What must I change in order to save special characters (and line breaks) into SQL correctly?

Comment: why do you need backquates surrounding reactions?? and have you seen the value of yourname and yourmessage after using trim function?

Comment: @HemantMetalia I don't really need them but keeping them isn't an issue...

Comment: is this value coming correcly: $_POST['yourmessage'])?? as in the correct format?

Comment: second question, the db is SQL

Comment: MS SQL server 2005/2008 or mySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might need to use [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php), probably like so:

```
$yourname = utf8_decode(trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['yourname'])));
$yourmessage = utf8_decode(trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['yourmessage'])));
```

Side note: straight string concatenation is just asking for a SQL injection attack. Check out [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) if this is going to be in any kind of production environment.

Comment: Works great, thanks! However, I don't see your point concerning the side note. I'm using mysql_real_escape_string to prevent SQL injection attack. What do I need to do more?

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. I didn't see the call inside your `trim()` call. *Gets another cup of coffee*

Comment: With your solution, everything works fine except for line breaks (I get "nn"). How can I do to fix this?

Comment: Not sure, but now that I look again, it may have something to do with the fact that you use `mysql_real_escape_string` first. It might make sense to move that call to the very outside so it happens last. Not sure if that'll fix it, but it's probably a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

its nothing to do with JQuery or PHP. Its with how you are handling the request and inserting the data probably.

Make sure you cover all the following grounds:

- Make sure that all your table columns in mysql are UTF8
- Add this to your mysql macro or right after you create mysql connection: `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` or `mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -uyour_user -p`
- Add this to the top of all your php pages (or master if you have one): `Header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`
- And of course the meta-tag, that sets encoding in the html/template file.

Comment: I'll make sure they are set this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

probabaly its about you dont work with UTF-8.if you start with your code as UTF-8 you wont get error like this. dont forget all ajax request send based on UTF-8

Other way you can convert text with mb_convert_encoding function or iconv function